# Changing embed text through a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a new coder and I was looking through the youtube embeds and noticed they had a common factor in them. I wanted to see if I could choose which video to embed through that common factor. This is what I believe I've done, however, it is not working. My code is below and any criticism is helpful, thanks. :D

Code:

```html
<input type="text" id="videoName" name="video"</input> 
    <br>
<input type="button" id="search" width="10" length="20" name="Search">
    <br>
    <search onclick="title()"></search>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function(title){
var texts = document.getElementById('videoName').value
      
    </script>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src= "var video = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + texts" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    }
    <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made the following changes:

1. use `<button>` for submitting the result instead of two input buttons
2. remove the `search` tag since it is not a valid tag
3. the function you created may need a name, like `function getTitle(){}`. Originall, you put the title inside the parenthesis, since you don't need to pass the `title` in and the `title` will be gotten inside the function. Therefore, we can just it blank.

```
<input type="text" id="videoName" name="video" /> <br>
<button type="submit" onClick="getTitle()" id="search" width="10" length="20" name="Search">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getTitle() {
        var texts = document.getElementById('videoName').value;
    }
</script>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="var video = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + texts" frameborder="0"
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iframe is one of the method through we can embed any video and make it run.
We can acheive this by making following changes in your code:

1. The function you have create is missing name it should to be like this

   ```
    function getTitle() {
            var texts = document.getElementById('videoName').value;
        }
   ```
2. You want to add the video on click of button on the basis of name user has input. So you need to change the source of iframe on click action.
   Add id to your iframe element and change source on click of button

   ```
        var iframe= document.getElementById('youtubeframe');
        iframe.src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + texts;
   ```

For your reference  :  https://jsfiddle.net/obfL1k9q/